# How to implement Tower of Hanoi in AEM Sightly

Tags: math, recursion, aem, sightly

I'm trying to implement recursive algorithm solving Tower of Hanoi
problem in Sightly. I know this approach may not have many obvious
practical applications, I treat it as a puzzle. I end up with something
like this:

```
<sly data-sly-template.step="${@ n, src, aux, dst}" data-sly-unwrap>
  <sly data-sly-test="${n > 0}" data-sly-unwrap>
    <sly data-sly-call="${step @ n = (n-1), src = src, aux = dst, dst = aux}" data-sly-unwrap/>
    ${src} -> ${dst}<br/>
    <sly data-sly-call="${step @ n = (n-1), src = aux, aux = src, dst = dst}" data-sly-unwrap/>
  </sly>
</sly>

<sly data-sly-call="${step @ n = 3, src = 'A', aux = 'B', dst = 'C'}" data-sly-unwrap/>
```

However, it doesn't compile as the Sightly doesn't support arithmetic
operators like `-`. I don't need to count from 3 to 0, we may do it the
opposite way, as the direction doesn't matter here. I just need some
kind of counter with following features:

1. we can increment or decrement it,
2. we can check if equals to zero or some constant number.

I thought about using string. Empty string would be zero, 'x' would be
1, 'xx' would be 2 and so on. We can check if a string equals to a
number (`n == 'xxxx'`). We can even increment it, using Sightly [string
formatter](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/sightly.html#String%20Formatting):

```
${'x{0}' @ format = [n]}
```

However, the above expression can't be used as a parameter in the
`data-sly-call` or in the `data-sly-test`. We can only display it
immediately and no further processing is available.

Do you have any other idea if there is some counter I can use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use empty nested arrays: `[]` is 0, `[[]]` is 1, `[[[]]]` is 2, etc.
If `n` is a number then:

- `n[0]` decrements it (as we get the inner array),
- `[n]` increments it (as we wrap the `n` with a new array),
- `data-sly-test` will accept all n > 0 (at least two opening brackets).

The working code for n=3 would look like this:

```
<sly data-sly-template.step="${@ n, src, aux, dst}" data-sly-unwrap>
  <sly data-sly-test="${n}" data-sly-unwrap>
    <sly data-sly-call="${step @ n = n[0], src = src, aux = dst, dst = aux}" data-sly-unwrap/>
    ${src} -> ${dst}<br/>
    <sly data-sly-call="${step @ n = n[0], src = aux, aux = src, dst = dst}" data-sly-unwrap/>
  </sly>
</sly>

<sly data-sly-call="${step @ n = [[[[]]]], src = 'A', aux = 'B', dst = 'C'}" data-sly-unwrap/>
```

The interesting thing here is that such construction of integers is very similar to the [set-theoretic definition of natural numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers). It appears that Maths is useful in the web-development after all!